# web extensions: Update menu on firefox android

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-android

Before web extensions, I used `NativeWindow.menu.add` and achieved this on firefox android. [image: NativeWindow.menu.add]

- <s>Add menu</s> I can do this from `browser_action.default_title`.
- Update text from the addon (like '936')

How do I do this in web extensions?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Legacy_Firefox_for_Android/API/NativeWindow/menu/add

previous code

```
// getWindow
const { Cu } = require('chrome');
/**
  * get current browser window for firefox addon
  *
  * @returns {ChromeWindow|null} browser window
  * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWindowMediator#getMostRecentWindow()
  */
module.exports = () => {
  /* global Services:false */
  Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
  return Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
};

// index.js
menuId = getWindow().NativeWindow.menu.add({
  name: 'Page for Hatebu (-)',
  callback: handleClick,
});

getWindow().NativeWindow.menu.update(
  menuId,
  {
    name: `Page for Hatebu (${piece})`,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

After Firefox 57 you have to use [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) (aka Browser Extensions) for all Firefox extensions.

You can use [browserAction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction) to add an item to the Firefox menu on Android. And especially [browserAction.setTitle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/setTitle) to change the text.